# Calculating number of hours until business opens?

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate the timespan (in hours) between the current time, and when a business will open again.

I'm stuck moving to the next day when a business has closed for the day. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
    $storeSchedule = [
    'Mon' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Tue' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Wed' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Thu' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Fri' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Sat' => ['12:00 AM' => '01:00 AM', '09:00 AM' => '12:00 AM']
];

// current (or inputted time)
$timestamp = time();
$status = -1;
$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

    // create time objects from start/end times
    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
    $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);
    
    // Business will open later today
    if ($startTime > $currentTime) {
        $status = round(abs($currentTime - $startTime) / 3600,2);
        break;
    }
    
    // Business is open right now
    if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
        $status = 0;
        break;
    }
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "moving to the next day"? Please share the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Don't use day name abbreviations as your array keys, use the number of the day in the week - 0 for Sunday, up to 6 for Saturday. Use `date('w')` to get the day of the week number of your time that you want to check for. Instead of foreach, use a do-while loop. If you don't find a match on the current day, you increase your day number by 1, and if that goes over 6, you reset it to 0. Keep the loop going, until you found the next time the business will be open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example, see, if it works for you.

```
<?php

$storeSchedule = [
    'Mon' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM'],
    'Tue' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM'],
    'Wed' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM'],
    'Thu' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM'],
    'Fri' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM'],
    'Sat' => ['09:00 AM' => '12:00 PM', '01:00 PM' => '06:00 PM'],
    'Sun' => 'closed'
];

// current (or inputted time)
$timestamp = time();
$status = -1;
$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$schedule = isset($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)]) ? $storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] : 'closed';

if ($schedule == 'closed') {
    $status = 'Closed for todays';
} else {
    foreach ($schedule as $startTime => $endTime) {
        //Create DateTime objects from start/end times
        $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
        $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);

        // Business will open later today
        if ($startTime > $currentTime) {
            $status = round(abs($currentTime->getTimestamp() - $startTime->getTimestamp()) / 3600,2).' hours until opening';
            break;
        }

        // Business is open right now
        if (($startTime <= $currentTime) && ($currentTime <= $endTime)) {
            $status = 'Open now';
            break;
        }

        // Business is closed for today
        if ($currentTime > $endTime) {
            $status = 'Closed for today';
        }
    }
}

echo $status;
?>
```